# Facebook blocking page sharing due to og:image

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm facing the following problem with the Facebook share button.

Some pages of my website are becoming unavailable to be shared. When I or anyone tries to share they get the following message:

> Sorry, this feature is not available at the moment: There was an error
>   processing this request. Try again later. ( I translated from my language to english)

If I try to debug using facebook debugger I get this:

> "Error Linting URL    An internal error occurred while linting the URL."

Comments form are also disabled by facebook on this pages, and all comments posted vanished.

I noticed that what is being blocked by Facebook is only the image in og:image - Something like: http://images.mydomain.com/folder/file.jpg - If I change the image url to any other file, Facebook debugger will be able to scrape the page again and will show no errors.

Trying to scrape the og:image of the blocked page will throw the following error:

> This link is blocked, or you have triggered an excessive amount of
>   scrapes. If you think you're seeing this by mistake, please let us
>   know.

I really don't understand why this is happening. I'm not spamming on Facebook in any way. My website is just being very successful with millions users a day, and this may be causing a lot of Shares daily.

Comment: _“If you think you're seeing this by mistake, please let us know.”_ – so do that. (Pretty sure that links to some kind of form or something, where you can describe the issue to Facebook.)

Comment: the problem is that they never answer...